# RegEx won't limit max characters

Tags: regex

I am attempting to limit the length to 20 characters. The lower limit is honored but the upper limit is not.

```
^\+([\s]*[\d]+[\s]*){1,20}$
```

What do I need to do in order to prevent more than 20 characters?

Comment: you want all whitespaces and digits only?

Comment: Agreed. What are you matching? There may be a way to shape up the regex to provide a better solution.

Comment: @chad: You should edit your question and provide some valid and invalid input strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string can have spaces and digits, then you can use:

```
^\+[\d\s]{0,19}$
```

Comment: This appears to solve the issue and is the most concise pattern. Mine was a bit convoluted. I added the ^\+ to ensure the first character is a +. Thank you!

Comment: @anubhava, yes. I based on op's pattern

Comment: `^\+[\d\s]{1,20}$` will allow up to 21 characters now/ Also it will return input  `"+ "` as valid input. (without a single digit)

Comment: Understood. I knocked it down to 19. Thanks!

Comment: Count is still wrong, it should be `{0,19}` now but it will still return input `"+"`  or `"+ "` as an valid input.

Answer (score 2):

Limit `{1,20}` is being applied to whole group `([\s]*[\d]+[\s]*)`.

You can use a lookahead to assert min and max length:

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)\+\s*\d+\s*$
```

`(?=.{1,20}$)` is a positive lookahead that asserts length of input between `1` and `20`.

Comment: Why would applying the limit to the whole group be incorrect? I want to ensure the whole string isn't more than 20 characters long.

Comment: @chad: Yes I understand that you want `whole string isn't more than 20 characters long.` but what you have is going to allow max 20 repetitions of group `([\s]*[\d]+[\s]*)`